# Adding a pointer in array with pointers in c++

Tags: arrays, pointers, this

I have an array of pointers which is defined: `Users **u`, now I want to add one more object(pointer, because the class Users is abstract) in this array with this line: `this+= new Admin();` Also I have overloaded operator `+=` but still doesn't work. Does anyone know how can I do it without using 'this'??

Comment: You should include code of your operator overload attempt.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::vector<Users*>` when you need an array of dynamic size?

Comment: We need more information to answer this.  What do you mean by "it doesn't work".  Are you getting an error, if so what?  Please post your code on how you override the `+=` operator and what makes up `Users` & `Admin`

Comment: DataBase &operator+=(User *user){
        if(User::nbUsers==1){
            this->users=new User*[1];
            users[0]=user;
        }
        else{
            User**temp=new User *[User:nbUsers];
            for(int i=0; i<User::nmUsers-1; i++){
                temp[i]=users[i];
            }
            delete [] users;
            temp[User::nbUsers-1]=user;
            users=temp;
            temp=NULL;
        }
        return *this;
    }
@JNYRanger

Comment: @LaStéphanie Please edit your question to include that.  It's very difficult to read code in comments.